# Specify the name of its swagger api

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have a controller that is named `User` in which I have two GET methods to retrieve the user's information either by his mail, `GetUserByMail`, or by his mobile number, `GetUserByMobile`.

The problem is that when I generate my Swagger documentation I have both GET but not their names. They are both called "User" with their respective parameters "mail" or "mobile".

How do I specify the name of my API via the C# attributes for Swagger to include it correctly in the documentation?

Comment: Are you specifying the route name annotation ? Like this _[HttpGet("GetUserByMail")]_  If you dont, swagger will recognize both as _get_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576436/swagger-net-shows-controller-name-instead-of-endpoint-method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831986/show-name-from-route-in-swagger-documentation-using-swashbuckle

Answer (score 1):

```
 //This is important
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class PingController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Pong");
    }


}
```

The `[action]` indicates to swagger to use the method name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly specify the action methods' name, at which they will be accessed in your API:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public sealed class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("get-user-by-mail/{email}")]
    public object GetUserByMail(string email) { }

    [Route("get-user-by-mobile/{mobile}")]
    public object GetUserByMail(string mobile) { }
}
```

If you put your `RouteAttribute` on the whole class, it will create a single route for all the methods within it.